# Orientation Change resets Toolbar Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

What I'm exactly trying to achieve is to Override the Navigation Button of the Toolbar.
I referred [this](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/) link for doing so and its working fine unless there is an orientation change anywhere in the app. When an orientation change occurs, This behaviour is removed. It kind a resets the toolbar back button to its original behaviour (Go back or Navigate back).

I tried another approach by adding a button to the toolbar and Accessing it at the run time making it visible and gone when required. but the rotation issue still persists here. it resets the button state to the original state declared in the Layout file.

The Bottom Line :

1. I want to override the toolbar's navigation button (I have achieved this)
2. I want that behaviour to persist despite any Orientation change (I'm 
   Stuck here)

Answer (score 2):

Android considers screen orientation change as a [configuration change](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) that requires recreation of the running Activity. It means that first [OnDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) is called, followed by [OnCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)).

Your behaviour won't *persist* per se but if you do the required changes in OnCreate(), you'll have the same setup even after an orientation change. This of course refers to your second try where yo uadd the button during runtime.

**Edit:** If your MainActivity has the following attribute defined on top of it, OnDestroy and OnCreate won't get called:

```
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation
```

If you delete ConfigChanges.Orientation, those OnDestroy and OnCreate will be called when the screen orientation changes. Here's how it looks after the fix:

```
[Activity(Label = "AppSomething", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant? The MainActivity's (The only activity for a xamarin Form Project) OnCreate can set the button to have such behaviour for 1 time. I tried putting a debug point in the OnCreate Function of the MainActivity and Did an Orientation change, I didn't get any break point there. In override func of OnConfigurationChanged, I get the breakpoint. If that's the only possible solution to this problem then I would have to change my requirement.

Comment: @Abhinash My bad, by default Xamarin.Forms adds an attribute on top of MainActivity to stop those lifecycle events firing on orientation change. Check my edit for more information.

Comment: But wouldn't that make the entire app restart from the beginning?

Comment: @Abhinash No, it simply reinitializes a few things.